GeoServer leaks internal information in ServiceException
My GeoServer has issues reaching a database in a data store and includes detailed information in the service exception:
curl "https://example/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=foo&bbox=15.0%2C45.0%2C25.0%2C55.0&width=768&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=image%2Fpng"

results in
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "https://example.com:443/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting FeatureType, this should never happen!
Error getting FeatureType, this should never happen!Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to 123.123.123.123:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to 123.123.123.123:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
Connection to 123.123.123.123:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Permission denied (connect failed)
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>

The IP of the database server should never be visible to anyone but the GeoServer admin.
How can I make the service exceptions less verbose and stop this leakage of sensitive information?

GeoServer 2.24.2
Service Error Settings are set to "Skipping misconfigured layers" and the checkbox "Include stack trace in service exception" is not enabled.
Logging is set to PRODUCTION_LOGGING

I looked through https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/config.html and web searches but found no information regarding this.

This feels like a security issue. How to action is documented in https://geoserver.org/issues/ "send details to geoserver-security@lists.osgeo.org"

turn off verbose error messages

I am not sure if it is a configuration issue or a security issue and do not want to waste developers nerves. @IanTurton where do I find that option? I googled and searched through the docs, found nothing. Settings -> Global -> Service Response Settings -> Verbose XML output (pretty print) is disabled and should be unrelated. Do you mean https://docs.geoserver.org/2.24.x/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#include-stack-trace-in-service-exceptions ? That is already disabled (=default).

I forget exactly where the setting is, as a developer I always want to see the full error message. But I'm pretty sure that this exact issue has been addressed

you should look into a reverse proxy.

@Mapperz What for? If you mean to put it in front of the DB then the reverse proxy's address would also be leaked here.
